# C# UploadStringAsync not working

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, webclient, uploadstring

I am having a wcf service and I am calling a method like this:

```
public static void f5()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
        var data = File.ReadAllText("request.xml");
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
        client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "some string");            
        client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://differentdomain/wcf/Service.svc"), data);
    }

    public static void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        int cow = 0;
        cow++;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        f5();
    }
```

This program works perfectly when I don't use async method however the handler is not getting called soe some reason. The web service is hosted on a different computer on a different domain but the client and server are connected to same network. Most importanly everything works fine if I use UploadString instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is exiting right after the call to UploadStringAsync, so it doesn't have time to get the response. In the code below, if I remove the `Thread.Sleep` call at the end of the Main method, it will also not print anything. Try waiting for the response to arrive before exiting your program.

```
public class StackOverflow_11218045
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Echo(string text);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string Echo(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        string data = @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                            <s:Header/>
                            <s:Body>
                                <Echo xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
                                    <text>Hello</text>
                                </Echo>
                            </s:Body>
                        </s:Envelope>";
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/ITest/Echo");

        ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(baseAddress), "POST", data, evt);
        evt.WaitOne();
    }

    static void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result);
        ((ManualResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Sleep` call was just to show that you don't get the response because the program exits before it arrives. A better solution (I edited my code) would be to simply not exit until it happens (for example, using an event as shown above).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to get the Async method to work, you could try using the non-async method but make it work asynchronously using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx):

```
var client = new WebClient();
var data = File.ReadAllText("request.xml");
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "some string");

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    string returnVal = client.UploadString(new Uri("http://differentdomain/wcf/Service.svc"), data);
    Console.WriteLine(returnVal);
});
```

This is an overall better strategy, as it will work for all long-running operations and not just those which have an Async method and event handlers.

It should also make any communication/transport errors which occur easier to catch.